# удаление элемента односвязного списка с условием

Tags: c++, односвязный-список

не могу додуматься, как удалить из списка элемент, равный полусумме соседей.
а именно проблема с критерием отбора в этой строчке: 
    if (((data + p2->info)/ 2.0 == p->info)&&(data>0))
как ее изменить, чтобы условие полусуммы считывалось нормально?

```
void PoslList(List * head, List * tail)
{
int data = 0;
List * p = head->next;
while (p != tail)
{
    List *p1 = p->pred;
    List *p2 = p->next;
    data = p->pred->info;
    cout << data  <<  setw(6);
    if (((data + p2->info)/ 2.0 == p->info)&&(data>0))  
    {
        data = p->info;
        List *q = RemoveElement(p);
        delete p;
        p = q;
    }

    else
        p = p->next;


}
return;
```

}

Comment: Что не работает? Компилятор ошибку выдает?

Comment: при тестировании на списке 12345 вывод: 135. должен быть 15.
при тестировании на списке 12356 вывод 156. должен быть 1356. ошибка в условии удаления

Comment: что из себя представляет List::pred?

Answer (score 0):

```
void PoslList(List *head, List *tail)
{
    List *p = head, *q = head->next;
    while(q != tail) {
        if (q->info == (p->info + q->next->info) / 2 ) {
            p->next = q->next;
            delete q;
        }
      p = p->next;
      q = q->next;
    }
}
```